# going through a XML file with Delphi and NativeXML:

Tags: xml, delphi, nativexml

let's say that I've a XML file looking like this

```
<NOTE>
   <TO>
      <CONTACT>
         <NAME>Tove</NAME>
         <EMAIL>tove@home.com</EMAIL>
      </CONTACT>
      <CONTACT>
         <NAME>Biggles</NAME>
         <EMAIL>biggles@home.com</EMAIL>
      </CONTACT>
   </TO>
   <FROM>
      <CONTACT>
         <NAME>Jani</NAME>
         <EMAIL>jani@home.com</EMAIL>
      </CONTACT>
   </FROM>
   <HEADING>Reminder</HEADING>
   <BODY>Party this weekend!</BODY>
</NOTE>
```

with NativeXML (at least until version 3.06) and this code

```
procedure TForm1.btnLoad1st2ndClick(Sender: TObject);
// Load an XML document and show the nodes present by enumerating them. Here
// we do only levels 1 and 2. An iterative approach could show all levels deep
var
  i, j: integer;
  NodeLevel1, NodeLevel2: TXmlNode;
begin
  // Clear the memo and create instance
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  FXml.Clear;
  // Load the XML file
  FXml.LoadFromFile(edXmlFileOpen.Text);
  // The Root property contains the root node, we use it as a base
  if assigned(FXml.Root) then
  begin
    // Iterate through all the child nodes of Root (level 1)
    for i := 0 to FXml.Root.NodeCount - 1 do
    begin
      NodeLevel1 := FXml.Root.Nodes[i];
      // Add the name of each child to the memo
      Memo1.Lines.Add(string(NodeLevel1.Name));
      // Also iterate through the grandchilds (level 2)
      for j := 0 to NodeLevel1.NodeCount - 1 do
      begin
        NodeLevel2 := NodeLevel1.Nodes[j];
        // Add these names too, with an indent
        Memo1.Lines.Add(' ' + string(NodeLevel2.Name));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I get this response

```
TO
 CONTACT
 CONTACT
FROM
 CONTACT
HEADING
BODY
```

which is what I expected

but now I use NativeXML in version 4.07 and, with the same code, the result is

```
WhiteSpace
TO
 WhiteSpace
 CONTACT
 WhiteSpace
 CONTACT
 WhiteSpace
WhiteSpace
FROM
 WhiteSpace
 CONTACT
 WhiteSpace
WhiteSpace
HEADING
 CharData
WhiteSpace
BODY
 CharData
WhiteSpace
```

You guess that in real life, the XML will be a little bit more complicated. Is there a way to get, as simply as possible, the same result with the current version of NativeXML then before?

Thanks for your help

PS: by the way, I've take a look at this post
"[How do I iterate through similar nodes in an XML document using NativeXML in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483436/how-do-i-iterate-through-similar-nodes-in-an-xml-document-using-nativexml-in-del)"
but the first proposed solution, which is similar to my sample, doesn't work. And the second one implies to use a list of nodes, what I would like to avoid.

Comment: I've found a workarond; not very pretty but it works instead of
// Add the name of each child to the memo
Memo1.Lines.Add(string(NodeLevel1.Name));

I've added the test
if (not (NodeLevel1 is TsdWhiteSpace)) and (not (NodeLevel1 is TsdCharData)) then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should simply use `xml.root.ElementCount` and `xml.root.Elements[i]` properties instead of `NodeCount` & `Nodes[]` (the same with `nodelevel1.`) to achieve desired ouput